# Rock, Paper, Scissors Game shows both win and lose messages

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm currently working through a `Rock, Paper, Scissors` project that plays out in the console (this is for The Odin Project, front end coming soon).

Here is what my script looks like for reference:

```
<script>
    function computerPlay() {
      const choice = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]

      return choice[Math.floor(Math.random() * choice.length)]
    }

    function play(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
       const lose = console.log('You lose! ' + computerSelection + ' beats ' + playerSelection + '!')
       const win = console.log('You win! ' + playerSelection + ' beats ' + computerSelection + '!')

      if (playerSelection === computerSelection) {
        return console.log("It's a draw! Try again!")
      }

      if (playerSelection === "rock" && computerSelection === "Paper") {
        return lose
      }

      if (playerSelection === "rock" && computerSelection === "Scissors") {
        return win
      }

      if (playerSelection === "paper" && computerSelection === "Scissors") {
        return lose
      }

      if (playerSelection === "paper" && computerSelection === "Rock") {
        return win
      }

      if (playerSelection === "scissors" && computerSelection === "Rock") {
        return lose
      }

      if (playerSelection === "scissors" && computerSelection === "Paper") {
        return win
      }
    }

    function game() {
      playerSelect = prompt("Welcome to Rock, Paper, Scissors! Which one do you choose? \n")
      compSelect = computerPlay()

      console.log("Player chose " + playerSelect)
      console.log("Computer chose " + compSelect)
      console.log(play(playerSelect, compSelect))
    }
  </script>
```

Right now my output is showing both the win and lose conditions for any given choice like this:

```
Player chose rock
Computer chose Rock
You lose! Rock beats rock!
You win! rock beats Rock!
```

I chose to keep the win and lose messages in variables but I know I probably screwed some small detail up there. I've tried adding/removing the if else statements but both messages still show up no matter what choice.

I'm planning on making either choice case insensitive until I solve this error.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are calling your `console.log` at the beginning of the script, you are not saving them for later, you are running them and assigning their return value to a variable. What you could do is have a win and a lose variable that are function and then call them when the player is winning/loosing.

```js
function computerPlay() {
      const choice = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"];

      return choice[Math.floor(Math.random() * choice.length)];
    }

    function play(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
    // we are storing a function into the win and lose variable.
       const lose = () => console.log('You lose! ' + computerSelection + ' beats ' + playerSelection + '!');
       const win = () => console.log('You win! ' + playerSelection + ' beats ' + computerSelection + '!');

      if (playerSelection === computerSelection) {
        return console.log("It's a draw! Try again!")
      }

      if (playerSelection === "rock" && computerSelection === "Paper") {
        return lose()
      }

      if (playerSelection === "rock" && computerSelection === "Scissors") {
        return win()
      }

      if (playerSelection === "paper" && computerSelection === "Scissors") {
        return lose()
      }

      if (playerSelection === "paper" && computerSelection === "Rock") {
        return win()
      }

      if (playerSelection === "scissors" && computerSelection === "Rock") {
        return lose()
      }

      if (playerSelection === "scissors" && computerSelection === "Paper") {
        return win()
      }
    }

    function game() {
      playerSelect = 'rock';
      compSelect = computerPlay();

      console.log("Player chose " + playerSelect);
      console.log("Computer chose " + compSelect);
      // You don't need to console.log the return value of a console.log
      play(playerSelect, compSelect);
    }
    
    game();
```

Comment: This worked! I hadn't considered that I was just storing and printing those statements without a condition. Thanks so much!

Comment: I'm glad i could help !

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `lose` and `win` variables to their string values instead of `console.log("/message/")`.

Your `lose` and `win` variable declarations are already printing their messages instead of storing them, since your code calls an instance of `console.log()`.

That way, when you return either win or lose, your  `console.log(play(playerSelect, compSelect))` will receive a string, and then print it.